# Adding errors in quadrature for mean values

Tags: error, image-processing

I understand that for $ Z = \frac{X}{Y}$, the error in quadrature would be calculated as,

$\Delta Z = Z \sqrt{\big( \frac{\Delta X}{X} \big)^2 + \big( \frac{\Delta Y}{Y} \big)^2}$.

In my case, X and Y are the mean intensities of some regions of interest (ROI) within an image. Therefore, would the

$\big( \frac{\Delta X}{X} \big)$

correspond to the standard deviation of the voxels divided by the mean of the voxels within the ROI?

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: Although it's not clear what $X$ and $Y$ are--perhaps they are dimensions of rectangles that approximate the ROIs?--I'm pretty sure you would need to square the terms under the square root. To appreciate the distinction, suppose $\Delta X/X$ and $\Delta Y/Y$ were very small, say $0.005$ each: then your formula would calculate $\Delta Z/Z$ as $0.1$, which is far too large.

Comment: Sorry, type. Quadrature requires the bracketed terms be squared. The values are image intensities (we can presume they are unitless for this example).

Comment: "Quadrature" ordinarily can mean [many things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature), but none of the common ones appear to correspond to your use here. What exactly do you mean by this term?  Is it perhaps related to a theory of error propagation and an application of the [delta method](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=delta%20method)?

Comment: Yes, obviously I am not too keen on my statistics, so please bare with me. Because my measurement involves taking the ratio of the mean quantitities, I thought I would have to add the errors in quadrature. Perhaps I am mistaken, and should refer to a stats book! The information was taken from this website http://www.upscale.utoronto.ca/PVB/Harrison/ErrorAnalysis/Propagation.html